# nginx blocking images in dokuwiki

Tags: nginx, dokuwiki

Recently I did a deployment of dokuwiki on nginx and realized that images were not loading. To fix this problem for templates the following rule that to be added to the nginx.conf

`location ~ ^/wiki/(lib)/ {
                allow all; #
        }`

This worked for the themes but images embedded in articles will still not show. Any ideas on what nginx rules need to be added to make the images uploaded to dokuwiki visible?

Also for anyone interested here are the steps I followed to deploy the wiki http://www.bigthinkingapplied.com/launching-a-private-wikipedia-using-dokuwiki/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely the case that images are auto-saved to a separate location. (On the dokuwiki.org home page, they are under _media/) -- you probably need to add a rule to nginx to handle requests to this folder-- something like:

```
location /_media/ { #do file serving here }
```

Comment: Thanks Gary. It turns out the instructions in my tutorial were just fine and nginx rules are correct and already in place. My test was done using a wiki backup which was not restored correctly as it was missing the media directories from under /data in dokuwiki.